# Type conversion in C from int to char

Tags: c, string, casting, integer

I am new to C and quite used to python. I have integers 0 and 1 say five integers I want to convert them into string array. Say 
`int a=1,b=1,c=0`. I want to make a string `str` with value 110. In python it was two line script but unfortunately in C I am unable to do so.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for [`sprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)?

Comment: What did the string chapter of your C programming book tell you to use?

Comment: Do you want something like `char str[4] = {a + '0', b + '0', c + '0'};`?

Comment: Maybe `char buffer[20]; sprintf(buffer, "%d", a*100 + b*10 + c);`. It's not very clear what you actually want, please elaborate your question.

Comment: @mch You mean `char str[4] = {a + '0', b + '0', c + '0', '\0'};` ?

Comment: @MayurK you can add the `'\0'`, but it is not recessary. If the initializer list has less elements than the array all missing elements will be initialized to `0`. Therefore the number of elements is required, otherwise the string will not be terminated.

Comment: @mch: Yes. It will be initialized to 0 and that is the problem. String should be terminated with '\0' right?

Comment: @MayurK `'\0' == 0`; `\0` is an octal escape sequence that is replaced by the character with character code 0, so not specifying it results in the missing initialization element being automatically initialized to 0, a.k.a. `'\0'`.

Comment: It worked!. Problem was I was dealing with linked list and structures so was getting confused.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is too broad, to figured why you cant do that u need to understand the C data types, strings in c and no of bytes allocated to each data types.

In the above question you have declared int a=0; what happens in the memory is 4 bytes of stack memory(again based on the scope of the variable memory is allocated in stack or heap) is allocated to variable a and value '0' is stored in it

The strings in C is a ('\0') null terminated character array. for each char type a 1 byte memory is allocated.

So now u can store some ascii values(3 bytes + Null byte) in int data type. And using type casting can deference it as string in c

Comment: It worked!. Problem was I was dealing with linked list and structures so was getting confused.